# How to change one entire row into the column headers? please advise me on this

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    def decode(self, s):
        result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s)
        return self._decode(result)

    def _decode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            try:
                return int(o)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    return float(o)
                except ValueError:
                    return o
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
        elif isinstance(o, list):
            return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
        else:
            return o

with open('ouput_data.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f,cls=Decoder)
#print(data)
list=[]
list=(data['data'])
df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['id','value'])
support_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(1,10),'value_aux':''})
final_df = support_df.merge(df,how='left')
final_df['value'] = np.where(final_df['value'].isna(),final_df['value_aux'],final_df['value'])
#print(final_df)
final_df = final_df.drop(columns='value_aux')
#final_df=final_df.drop(['id'],axis=1)
final_df=final_df.T
print(final_df)
```

**And my final_df output looks like:**

```
        0   1  2  3          4        5  6  7  8
id      1   2  3  4          5        6  7  8  9
value  NY  11     D  531293696  5202013
```

Like id is one row and value in one row....

Now i need that entire id row into **column headers** how can i do this....advise me that how to edit the code accordingly..

If possible please edit and post here it would be helpful...

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired output? Your question can be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: whatever the id row here going to be column headers like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .... everything is column header and value row is going to be 1st row

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
df.columns = df.loc['id',:].values
df.drop('id', axis=0, inplace=True)

df
        1   2  3          4        5    6    7    8    9
value  NY  11  D  531293696  5202013  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

df.columns
Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='object')
```

Comment: i don't understand it will change the first entire into the column headers to the second row?

Comment: @user11646543 yes. if will turn the `id` row to column headers and set the `value` row to first row

Comment: after the df.drop('id', axis=0, inplace=True) i am trying to print the df it shows none. please advise me on this

Comment: df.columns
Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='object') it doesnot only contain 9 elements there is 190 elements there for example i gave 10 so i cannot create these many elements by typing tell me anyother way to make as column headers and i dont understand this line where should i include this code in my code?

Comment: dude.... you only need the first two lines. all it does is to set the first row to column headers and drop it afterwards. you just have to put those two lines at the end of your code

Comment: yeah i did brother!!!! i tried to print the dataframe after the df.drop('id', axis=0, inplace=True) but its printing 'None'.Sorry if i proceed wrong .

Comment: either try without the drop line or you have to give better input data. it is working for the final_df output you printed

Comment: or try to change the line `final_df=final_df.T` to `final_df=final_df.set_index('id').T`